# RavenDB changes metadata "Raven-Entity-Name"

Tags: metadata, ravendb

I noticed that when I add a document to RavenDB and see the "Raven-Entity-Name" metadata it makes it plural. E.g. if my model name was `Product` it changes it to `Products`. Why such kind for behavior?

If I have create an index I am forced to use `docs.Products`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's part of the philosophy of RavenDB to do convention over configuration, so it does this by default.

But you can override it if you want to, you can do something like this:

```
_documentStore = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080/" };
_documentStore.Conventions.FindTypeTagName = t =>
{
    if (t.Name == "MyClass")
        return "MyClassBlahBlah";
    else
        return Raven.Client.Util.Inflector.Pluralize(t.Name); 
};

_documentStore.Initialize();
```

See [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/8096df5ee34fa6ce/) on the RavenDB discussion group for more info

Comment: so this means for every model i will have to write code. Is there any single point configuration whereby it stops pluralizing for the application or ravendb itself?

Comment: @ajay_whiz, Matt says everything you need to stop pluralizing. Try: _documentStore.Conventions.FindTypeTagName = t => t.Name;

Comment: Thanks for this! Solution also helps when you're trying to save a doc with a non-standard Id after loading and changing it.