# RavenDB throws a JSON deserialisation error when retrieving document

Tags: c#, ravendb

I've just completed a round of refactoring of my application, which has resulted in my removing a project that was no longer required and moving its classes into a different project. A side effect of this is that my `User` class, which is stored in RavenDB, has a collection property of a type moved to the new assembly. As soon as I attempt to query the session for the `User` class I get a `Json` deserialisation error. The issue is touched upon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224248/ravendb-throws-casting-exception-after-models-namespace-change) but the answers don't address my issue. Here's the offending property:

```
{
  "OAuthAccounts": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[
      [Friendorsement.Contracts.Membership.IOAuthAccount, 
      Friendorsement.Contracts]], mscorlib",
    "$values": []
  },
}
```

`OAuthAccounts` is a collection property of `User` that used to map here:

> System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[Friendorsement.Contracts.Membership.IOAuthAccount, Friendorsement.Contracts]]

It now maps here:

> System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[Friendorsement.Domain.Membership.IOAuthAccount, Friendorsement.Domain]]

`Friendorsement.Contracts` no longer exists. All of its types are now in `Friendorsement.Domain`

I've tried using `store.DatabaseCommands.StartsWith("User", "", 0, 128)` but that didn't return anything.

I've tried looking at `UpdateByIndex` but not got very far with it:

```
store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName",
    new IndexQuery {Query = "Tag:Users"},
        new[]
        {
            new PatchRequest { // unsure what to set here }
        });
```

I'm using Raven 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a simple sample application that shows you the patching Metadata. While your example is a little different this should be a good starting point

```
namespace SO19941925
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IDocumentStore store = new DocumentStore
                                   {
                                       Url = "http://localhost:8080",
                                       DefaultDatabase = "SO19941925"
                                   }.Initialize();

            using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    session.Store(new User {Name = "User" + i});
                }
                session.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                List<User> users = session.Query<User>().Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow()).ToList();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} SO19941925.Users", users.Count);
            }

            Operation s = store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName",
                new IndexQuery {Query = "Tag:Users"},
                new ScriptedPatchRequest
                {
                    Script = @"this['@metadata']['Raven-Clr-Type'] = 'SO19941925.Models.User, SO19941925';"
                }, true
                );
            s.WaitForCompletion();
            using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                List<Models.User> users =
                    session.Query<Models.User>().Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow()).ToList();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} SO19941925.Models.Users", users.Count);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    internal class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace SO19941925.Models
{
    internal class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Based on the initial answer above, here is the code that actually solves the OP question:

```
store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName",
    new IndexQuery {Query = "Tag:Users"},
    new ScriptedPatchRequest
    {
        Script = @"this['OAuthAccounts']['$type'] = 
            'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[
            [Friendorsement.Domain.Membership.IFlexOAuthAccount, 
            Friendorsement.Domain]], mscorlib';",
        }, true
        );
```

Comment: Cheers Shawn - whilst I don't need to get at the metadata of the actual document, it's good to see an example of the script that I can start to play around with. I'll see if I can get something working and post my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible solutions:

Option 1: Depending on what state your project is in, for example if you are still in development, you could easily just delete that collection out of RavenDB from the Raven Studio and recreate all those User documents.  All the new User documents should then have the correct class name and assembly and should then deserialize correctly.  Obviously, if you are already in production, this probably won't be a good option.

Option 2: Depending on how many User documents you have, you should be able to manually edit each one to specify the correct C# class name and assembly, so that they will be deserialized correctly.  Again, if you have too many objects to manually modify, this may not be a good option; however, if there are just a few, it shouldn't be too bad to open each one up go to the metadata tab and paste the correct value for "Raven-Entity-Name" and "Raven-Clr-Type".

Comment: It is a production system, so option 1 is out. I'm looking for a way to patch the database in case this comes up again in the future. I could do this one manually but it would be a workaround rather than a solution

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
Advanced.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex(
    "Raven/DocumentsByEntityName",
        new IndexQuery {Query = "Tag:Album"},
        new []{ new PatchRequest() { 
            Type = PatchCommandType.Modify, 
            Name = "@metadata", 
            Nested= new []{ 
                new PatchRequest{
                    Name= "Raven-Clr-Type",
                    Type = PatchCommandType.Set,
                    Value = "Core.Model.Album, Core" }}}},
        false);
```