# How to check if table (entity) exists in RavenDB

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb, nservicebus

I am querying built-in TimeoutData entity in RavenDB using Raven.Client.Lightweight 2.5 library to get specific timeout document. It is possible that TimeoutData does not exist in the database because no document is stored there yet. In that case NotSupportedException is thrown when you try to query it.

Currently I have created workaround for this situation:

```
try
{
    timeoutData = _session.Query<TimeoutData>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Headers.ContainsValue(someValue));
}
catch (NotSupportedException)
{
    return null;
}
```

Is it possible to verify if TimeoutData exist without using try-catch?
I have also tried the following code but it returns false when documents exist in TimeoutData entity:

```
if (!_session.Query<TimeoutData>().Any())
{

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. `NotSupportedException` will only be thrown if we can't actually process the query.
Are you interested in a specified document, or in whatever anything exists there?

Comment: I am interested whether TimeoutData entity (table) exists in RavenDB at all. NotSupportedException is also thrown when TimeoutData does not exist, but I would like to implement more solid solution.

Comment: `if (!_session.Query<TimeoutData>().Any())` This should give you that informtion

Comment: Turns out that I had to turn off pluralization of entity names and after that `_session.Query<TimeoutData>().Any()` started to work. This post helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635954/ravendb-changes-metadata-raven-entity-name. And also TimeoutData is NServiceBus entity for storing deferred messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that I had to turn off pluralization of entity names and after that `_session.Query<TimeoutData>().Any()` started to work. Before doing that query tried to find entity named `TimeoutDatas`.

This post helped me: [RavenDB changes metadata "Raven-Entity-Name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635954/ravendb-changes-metadata-raven-entity-name).

And also I forgot to mention that `TimeoutData` is NServiceBus entity for storing deferred messages.